# cron - "is a directory" error

Tags: cron

I am running a cron job on my hosting like

```
/usr/lib/php -q /home/name/public_html/runscript.php
```

the email alert says

```
/bin/sh: /usr/lib/php: is a directory
```

I am not sure if this is an error with the cron statement or not. I can't find much online.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `/usr/bin/php` instead.

Comment: You can also type in terminal 'whereis php' to locate the correct path.

Comment: I've tried changing to /usr/bin/php but this just sends back a load of errors. Like - Cannot send cookie, headers already sent, etc.
If I access the script without cron I get no errors.

Comment: I can't debug your script without seeing it (and I don't know PHP), but keep in mind that if its in the system crontab, cron will execute it as root and will use a pretty minimal path if PATH is not explicitly defined in the crontab. Also, if I'm not mistaken, your jobs will execute in the root directory, i.e. '/', so any relative paths will be broken.

Comment: Also what command do you use to "access the script without cron"?